# Moving whole Google Earth path?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a KML-file with a path in Google Earth that is slightly displaced.  And I don't want to move each coordinate manually.

How can I move all of the coordinates together?

I think [this site](http://kml.inovmapping.com/Jerusalem-Old-City-Walls) is using the same kml as I do. It depicts a city wall that is off. It should be moved like 100meters to the south so it don't crosses the major road that is north of it (as it does now). Or if you want to be more precise, each nod is of by longitude 0,000182 and lattitude 0,001217 if my calculation is right.

Comment: What are the parameters of the displacement (or the nature of it, at least)?

Comment: @martinf I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: The kml data format is pretty straight forward so I might write some script to manipulate each node. But it really should be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), with the help of a sql query parsed through spatialite.

```
ogr2ogr translated_kml.kml original.kml -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ShiftCoordinates(geometry,x,y) FROM world"
```

Where x and y are what you want to shift by, in the units of the kml file.

Comment: Perfect, also in the Ubuntu reositary. No I just need to find some time to try it. What would this do to do to the altitude?

Comment: It would depend on what the elevations for the features are set to.  If they are set to 'clamp to ground' then they will just be adjusted to fit the ground elevation at the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Because KML coordinates are geodetic, a rigorous solution with known rotation-scale-translation parameters would require use of a geodetic computation engine, such as can be found in [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/) (which is not "just" a spatial DBMS).

However, your needs indicate that a simple (crude) treatment of the lon-lat coordinates *as though* they were planar (i.e., 2D cartesian) coordinates would be adequate.
Here's how I've accomplished exactly the same:

copy and paste the coordinate string to a text editor

globally edit them to simple CSV format

import the CSV coordinates to a COGO program (such as [Copan](http://www.underhill.ca/software/copan-windows))

do the transformation

export the transformed coordinates

do the "reverse" edit-reformat-re-paste back into KML

Comment: (i have trouble with numbered lists!)